# Magento 'Add to Cart' JQuery issue?

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I have an issue in Magento where if I access individual products and add them to the cart, it tries to load an image (an image that states the product has been added successfully) which doesn't seem to be present, and doesn't add the product to the cart until you **refresh** the page.

[image: When adding the product (from the product page) to the cart and inspecting the element I get this error and the image isn't able to load.]

Could this be a potential conflict?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It is showing the errors.

Comment: jQuery is not defined usually means the library wasn't loaded. Is jQuery loaded into your site? Afaik it is not standard for Magento to do so.

Comment: @Charlie Check the page source if there is jQuery.js file is loaded ?